# Android 6.0. Crop photo: extras.getParcelable("data") = null

Tags: android

android 6.0, Device Nexus Galaxy S.

1. Take photo
2. Crop photo
3. Set image to ImageView

Method crop photo:

```
    private void performCrop(Intent data) {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myPhotoFile), "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", ImageFactory.getAvatarWidth());
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", ImageFactory.getAvatarHeight());
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
```

**myPhotoFile**: /storage/emulated/0/myphoto_2383996e1fd8210/myphoto_1487940877714

size : 2062768 bytes.

Get result:

```
         @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        onActivityResultPicCrop(resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void onActivityResultPicCrop(int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
                Bitmap.Config config = selectedImage.getConfig();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutService.rootView
                    .findViewById(md.qsystems.android.profileapp.R.id.imageViewAvatar);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            updateAvatar(false);
        }
}
```

But "extras" is  NULL and as result throw NPE.

On Android 4.4 (KitKat) it's work nice, but on Android 6.0 NOT.

Comment: There is no action `com.android.camera.action.CROP` in android

Comment: Please use an [image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), rather than relying on something that does not exist on many Android devices (`com.android.camera.action.CROP`).

Comment: I use this crop lib: github.com/jdamcd/android-crop . As result my code is simple and clean. And it's work on Android 4.0 and Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

> Extra is null because your intent probably failed cropping.  Consider
>   adding a test for the return code.
>
> ```
> @Override
>     public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
>         if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>
>             onActivityResultPicCrop(resultCode, data);
>         }
>     }
> ```

My code:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        onActivityResultPicCrop(resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

But it's not help. I get the same NPE.